# Origine du mariage de la carpe et du lapin

Tags: expressions, étymologie

L'expression « [mariage de la carpe et du lapin](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mariage_de_la_carpe_et_du_lapin) » est bien établie, et désigne l'alliance de deux choses incompatibles. Notamment, [elle aurait fréquemment servi à désigner les couples formés d'un noble et d'une roturière](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-l/864-le-mariage-de-la-carpe-et-du-lapin.html), à l'époque où c'était mal vu.

[Google ngram semble indiquer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mariage+de+la+carpe+et&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&s&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmariage%20de%20la%20carpe%20et%3B%2Cc0) qu'elle serait apparue un peu avant 1900. Chercher dans Google Books donne des indices, mais rien de concluant. [Cette fable](http://votewatch.blog.tdg.ch/archive/2011/09/10/la-veritable-origine-de-l-expression-le-mariage-de-la-carpe.html) est venue après.

**D'où vient l'expression ?** Pourquoi le lapin ?!

[image: Le lapin]

Comment: Je comprends bien le sens de l'expression. Qu'un lapin aille mal avec une carpe n'est pas un mystère pour moi. La question est : pourquoi un lapin et une carpe ? Pourquoi pas le mariage du taureau et de l'anguille ? ou celui du charpentier avec la flute de pan ?

Comment: Apparemment, la fable que tu as donnée en exemple [daterait de 1854](http://metaphora.over-blog.com/article-30101902.html). En revanche, tu as déjà bien fait tes recherches car je ne trouve pas d'élément permettant de compléter ce que tu as déjà mis dans ta question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On trouve deux sources<sup>1</sup> indiquant **1934** pour la locution « *mariage de la carpe et du lapin* » ([*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mariage), et [ici](https://books.google.com/books?id=oVZcAAAAMAAJ&q=%22mariage%20de%20la%20carpe%20et%22&dq=%22mariage%20de%20la%20carpe%20et%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kx5ZVfa0AsKGyASMtYE4&redir_esc=y) par exemple) :

> − Loc. *Mariage de la carpe et du lapin*. Alliance impossible,
>   association de deux réalités incompatibles. *Il est occupé à des
>   recherches nobiliaires visant à découvrir lequel des deux se mésallie,
>   dans le mariage de la carpe et du lapin* ([Montherl.](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_de_Montherlant),
>   [*Célibataires*](https://books.google.com/books?ei=BiBZVaKVK4KCyQSgh4GACQ&id=u79EAAAAYAAJ&dq=Les%20C%C3%A9libataires%20montherlant&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22mariage%20de%20la%20carpe%20et%20du%20lapin%22), 1934, p. 899).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* - TLFi à « *mariage* »]

J'ai trouvé la réponse [suivante](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?t=6797) où on cite *La puce à l'oreille : anthologie des expressions populaires avec leur origine* (une des sources du site de l'extrait précédent; cet auteur est aussi l'auteur de la deuxième source que j'ai présentée pour 1934); on y réfère entre autres à [*Alphonse Karr*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphonse_Karr) disant :

> On se rappelle ce charlatan qui disait : "J'ai guéri le roi du Maroc,
>   à preuve voici sa peau". Et cet autre, qui annonçait l'exhibition du
>   fruit des amours d'une carpe et d'un lapin, disant aux spectateurs :
>   "Voici le lapin dans cette cage et la carpe dans ce baquet, le père et
>   la mère; quant à l'enfant, il est pour le moment au jardin des
>   Plantes, où M. de [Lacépède](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard-Germain_de_Lac%C3%A9p%C3%A8de), grand animalier de France, m'a prié de le
>   faire conduire".
>
> [ Alphonse Karr, [*Bourdonnements*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/38643/38643-h/38643-h.htm), 1880. ]

La référence à M. de Lacépède permet de situer l'origine de l'anecdote à l'époque de la *Restauration* (1814-1830). L'anecdote souligne l'incongruité extraordinaire (similairement au latin [*asinus in tegulis*](http://audiolatinproverbs.blogspot.com/2008/05/asinus-in-tegulis.html) de Pétrone, par exemple, c'est-à-dire « un âne sur un toit »). On y parle de plus de *gastronomie* (sauge se mariant avec le porc), et de *religion* (jour maigre par opposition à jour gras). La réponse mentionne finalement que l'expression sortie du contexte de l'extrait n'a en effet commencé à circuler qu'à la fin du 19e.

Quant à une variante du poème, présentée en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13850/origine-du-mariage-de-la-carpe-et-du-lapin#comment26160_13850), où on indique 1854, on [note](http://metaphora.over-blog.com/article-30101902.html) au bas de la page que le poème original ne contenait pas de référence finale au *mariage du lapin et de la carpe* mais bien à : / *Homme, cette histoire est la nôtre :* / *A chaque être son élément* ! / *A chaque âme son aliment !* / *Ce qui fait vivre l'un fait souvent mourir l'autre.* /. Par ailleurs rien de ceci n'empêche que d'autres associations aux animaux que sont la [carpe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/carpe) et le [lapin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lapin) se soient aussi développées.

---

<sub>1. Dans la question, on présente une [source](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-l/864-le-mariage-de-la-carpe-et-du-lapin.html) qui dispose que :</sub>

> <sub>*Cette expression appliquée aux humains servait de métaphore au couple
>   composé d'un noble et d'une roturière*. Pour y pallier, le noble se
>   voit dans l'obligation de donner la main gauche à l'épouse pendant la
>   cérémonie, signifiant par ce geste qu'il ne transmettait son rang ni à
>   sa femme ni à leur progéniture. Il est à signaler que si le noble
>   donne sa main gauche, c'est parce que l'alliance normale entre deux
>   personnes de même rang se mettait à la main droite.</sub>

<sub>On n'indique aucunement sur quelle source on s'appuie pour formuler une telle affirmation (voir généralement [sources](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/sources-expressions.html) de cette source). On n'a pas démontré que le *mariage de la main [gauche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gauche)* (1680) est relié à la locution dont il est question ici; ni le *TLFi* ni *Rey/DHLF* n'en parlent.</sub>

Comment: Magnifique. À défaut d'avoir guéri le roi du Maroc, un illustre inconnu se sera taillé une place dans la langue. J'achète.

Comment: Merci, mais on ne peut cependant prendre la réponse pour du _cash_. Pourquoi expression-françaises parle de l'histoire du roturier et ne parle pas de l'anecdote alors qu'ils utilisent une source (puce à l'oreille) sur laquelle le Guichet du savoir base sa réponse et qui contient cette anecdote. C'est vraiment troublant; un jour je vais prendre le temps de consulter toutes leurs [sources](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/sources-expressions.html) et voir, car autrement on ne peut être certain de leur réponse ni de la mienne. Merci!

Answer (score 4):

L'expression vient d'une *[mésalliance](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9salliance)* lorsqu'un noble épouse une roturière.

Elle remonte au temps où la noblesse régnait en France, donc bien avant 1900.

Un chaud-lapin est un homme qui n'arrête pas de conquérir la gent féminine.

En conséquence, un lapin naturellement agité et primesautier est attiré par dame lapine, il court à l'échec avec une carpe qui a la réputation d'être muette et indolente. De plus, ils ne peuvent pas vivre dans l'environnement de l'autre : un lapin se noie dans l'eau, la carpe meurt dans l'air.

C'est en conséquence un mariage contre nature d'espèce animale et contre nature de tempérament.

Comment: Parmi les 37 animaux qui peuvent servir à désigner l'homme, je veux bien que le lapin soit un candidat parmi les autres (encore que s'il est si chaud que ça, pourquoi irait-il **marier** sa conquête ?). Mais pourquoi la carpe, alors ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks sans même aller jusqu'à la symbolique sexuelle du lapin, le lapin est une représentation d'activité et de vivacité, contrairement à la carpe qui est plutôt l'image du calme le plus ennuyeux ou serein selon les points de vue.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks J'ai complété ma réponse en tenant compte de celle de Yohann.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks J'ai upvote la réponse de cl-r puisqu'il a inclus ma réponse :D

Comment: @Glorfindel — J'ai utilisé le site https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ pour corrigé le lien.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks — J'ai complété ma réponse pour tenir compte d'une réalité insurmontable : l'environnement de l'autre est délétère pour chacun des protagonistes.

Comment: @Personne merci beaucoup

Answer (score -1):

Les nobles avaient le droit de chasse et mangeaient beaucoup de viandes (donc lapin), les roturiers et les roturières se nourrissaient comme principale et quasi unique source de protéine animale depuis le Moyen-Âge surtout de poissons d'élevages en étangs, forts nombreux en France. Donc le choix de la carpe qui était une des espèces les plus importantes dans ces plans d'eaux me parait logique.
à étudier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).